# Reading element by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HI I have following table

```
<table>
   <tr id="">
      <td class="row_class" id="row_id_1">233.00</td>
      <td class="row_class" id="row_id_2">2300</td>
      <td class="row_class" id="row_id_3">3.00</td>
      <td class="row_class" id="row_id_4">4.00</td>
      <td class="main" id="row_id_5">5.00</td>
      <td class="main" id="row_id_6">112.00</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to access row_class so I can add some formatting to the number. The code I have to access

```
   function formatCurrency() {
      alert();
      var num = document.getElementById('table td .row_class').value;
      var cNum = document.getElementById('table td .main').value;
      document.getElementById( val1 ).value = processformat( num );
      document.getElementById( val2 ).value = processformat( cNum );
   }
```

I get following error when i run it

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
var num = document.getElementById('table td .totalS').value;
```

I am trying to figure out the way to fix this error as well I am not sure if I need to apply .each function to apply the formatting to all elements?

Comment: So what is `val1` and then what is `val2`

Comment: `table td .row_class` is not the `id`, you can look at [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand that your code is trying to access a html tag which is given the 'id' attribute of whatever you define in the 'getElementById()' parameter.

```
var num = document.getElementById('table td .row_class').value;
```

Your code above is saying, get me the value of a html tag with 'table td .row_class' id and put it into 'num' variable which of course return null because you don't have any tag with id of 'table td .row_class'.

Two things you need to fix:

- getElementById() parameters, and
- the innerHTML property instead of       the value property

Your fix would be something like this:

```
function formatCurrency() {
        alert();
        var num = document.getElementById('row_id_1').value;
        var cNum = document.getElementById('row_id_5').value;
        document.getElementById('row_id_1').innerHTML= processformat(num);
        document.getElementById('row_id_5').innerHTML= processformat(cNum);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, You are trying to get value using `document.getElementById` with `className`, it is wrong.

```
function formatCurrency() {
        alert();
        var num = document.getElementById('row_id_1').value;
        var cNum = document.getElementById('row_id_5').value;
    }
```

In Jquery

```
   function formatCurrency() {
        alert();
        var num = $('#row_id_1').val();
        var cNum = $('#row_id_5').val();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function formatCurrency() {
            alert();
            var num = $('table td.row_class').html();
            var cNum = $('table td.main').html();
            document.getElementById(val1).value = processformat(num);
            document.getElementById(val2).value = processformat(cNum);
        }
```